# Visual C++ error C2665: none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

overloaded functions in the structure:

```
struct VARIABLE
{
    VARIABLE() : ShortName(NULL), MemberAddr(0), Description(NULL), DefaultValue(NULL), ValueSize(0), MemberType(NULL) {}


    template<typename U>
    VARIABLE(LPCTSTR sName, U const & member, U const & default, LPCTSTR desc) 
        : ShortName(sName), Description(desc)
        , MemberAddr((LPCBYTE)&member - (LPCBYTE)0), MemberType(new VTYPE<U>()) 
        , SizeAddr(0), SizeType(NULL)
    {
        SetDefault(default);
    }


    template<typename U>
    VARIABLE(LPCTSTR sName, U const & member, LPCTSTR desc) 
        : ShortName(sName), Description(desc)
        , MemberAddr((LPCBYTE)&member - (LPCBYTE)0), MemberType(new VTYPE<U>()) 
        , SizeAddr(0), SizeType(NULL)
    {}

    template<typename T, typename U>
    VARIABLE(LPCTSTR sName, NWArray<U> const & member, T const & size, LPCTSTR desc) 
        : ShortName(sName), Description(desc)
        , MemberAddr((LPCBYTE)&member - (LPCBYTE)0), MemberType(new VTYPE<NWArray<U> >()) 
        , SizeAddr((LPCBYTE)&size - (LPCBYTE)0), SizeType(new VTYPE<T>())
    {}

    ~VARIABLE() {
        if (ValueSize && DefaultValue) {
            delete DefaultValue; DefaultValue = NULL; ValueSize = 0;
        }
        if (MemberType) {
            delete MemberType; MemberType = NULL;
        }
    }

    template<typename U> void SetDefault(U default) { ValueSize = sizeof(U); DefaultValue = new U(default); }
    template <typename U> const U& GetDefault() const { return *(U*)DefaultValue; }

    LPCTSTR ShortName;
    intptr_t MemberAddr;
    TYPE *MemberType;
    LPCTSTR Description;
    LPVOID DefaultValue;
    DWORD ValueSize;
    DWORD SizeAddr;
    TYPE *SizeType;
};

#define INITVARTYPE(T) \
    T() { ::Init(this->GetInfDefmap(), (LPVOID)this); } \

#define BEGIN_INI_MAP_NOINIT(T) \
    LPCSTR GetTypeName() const { return #T; } \
    void *GetMember(const VARIABLE* memptr) const { return (void*)(((char*)this) + memptr->MemberAddr); } \
    const VARIABLE* GetInfDefmap() const { return InternalGetInfDefmap(); } \
    static VARIABLE* InternalGetInfDefmap() { \
    const T* pThis = 0; static VARIABLE map[] = { \

#define BEGIN_INI_MAP(T) \
    INITVARTYPE(T) \
    BEGIN_INI_MAP_NOINIT(T) \

#define END_INI_MAP() \
    VARIABLE() };\
    return map;} \

template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
VARIABLE FADDCLASS(T member, U ptr, V desc)
{
    VARIABLE(member, ptr, desc);
}

#define ADDCLASS(member) \
    FADDCLASS(#member, pThis->member, #member), \
```

It gave me this error when it tried to build the following process.

```
struct test
{
      char * name;

      BEGIN_INI_MAP(test)
        ADDCLASS(name)
      END_INI_MAP()
}
```

Error C2665: "VARIABLE::VARIABLE" none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types.
How do I solve this?
I've benn puzzling about this for a couple of hours.

Comment: You know the template function `FADDCLASS` is declared to return a `VARIABLE`, but has no `return` statement, right? And that isn't the only text in the error message. Post the *entire* error message with supporting descriptions in the question please, and make sure your copy/paste of `FADDCLASS` is accurate, because what is there now clearly won't work.

Comment: Are you building a Unicode build, by any chance? All those `LPCTSTR` parameters would then expect pointers to wide strings, but `#member` produces a narrow string literal - `"name"`, not `L"name"` or `_T("name")`

Answer (score 0):

The only overload of `VARIABLE::VARIABLE(...)` that takes 3 arguments takes an `LPCTSTR`, a generic type `U`, and another `LPCTSTR`. Why then does `FADDCLASS(...)` take 3 generics? Have it take `LPCTSTR` instead of `T` and `V`.